# How to update my total-items in angular-ui pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui

i wanna change my total-items in pagination when i call service and service return data.length

service called when i click search in input model

in my search html

```
<form ng-submit="submit(key1.index1)" ng-controller="searchController">
  <input type="text"
         class="form-control"
         id="inputKey1"
         placeholder="Enter Key 1"
         ng-model="key1.index1">
</form>
```

in my index html

```
<div ng-controller="searchController" >
  <pagination total-items="totalItems"
              ng-model="currentPage"
              max-size="maxSize"
              class="pagination-sm"
              boundary-links="true"
              ng-change="pageChanged()"
              items-per-page="items_per_page">
  </pagination>
</div>
```

in my controller

```
app.controller('searchController', function ($scope,Service) {
  $scope.totalItems = 0;
  $scope.submit = function (index1) {
    Service.getID("test", index1).then(function (listDocc) {
      $scope.totalItems = listDocc.length;  
      console.log( $scope.totalItems);
    });
  }
};
```

i got 20 in $scope.roralItems in function ,but my pagination it not update i very confuse

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('searchController', function ($scope,Service) {
$scope.totalItems = 0;
$scope.submit = function (index1) {
Service.getID("test", index1).then(function (listDocc) {
  $scope.totalItems = listDocc.length;  
 // try this 
  if(!$scope.$$phase){$scope.$apply();}
  console.log( $scope.totalItems);
 });
}
```

};

Comment: so for this you will need to check is $digest in progress or not if its not then use $scope.$apply(); for this you will need to do like this                                                       if (!scope.$$phase )                                            { $scope.$apply()                                                             }

Comment: how to check $digest cause i never use $digest in my controller . p.s.thank you

Comment: chk edited answer...!!! and $scope.$$phase is a flag which is maintained by angularjs to chk wthr $digest is in progress or not